# Selection doesn't propagate to backing bean with PrimeFaces datatable

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I just started learning JSF and PrimeFaces, and I'm having a hard time trying to get PrimeFaces' datatable to work. I have a checkbox-based selection mechanism (more than one row can be selected at the same time), so that clicking on the "Delete selected users" button triggers a method call to the backing bean to delete the corresponding users from the database.

The problem is that the selected rows are not stored in the backing bean's `selectedUsers` array, and I can't understand why, since my code is exactly the same as the one hosted on PrimeFaces' ShowCase. As a consequence, the button successfully triggers the confirmation dialog, but no user ever gets deleted from the system. Does anyone have any advice?

Thank you in advance!

**xhtml file**

```
<h:form id="tableForm">
    <p:dataTable id="userList" var="user" value="#{userListBean.userList}"
                 selection="#{userListBean.selectedUsers}" rowKey="#{user.username}">
        <f:facet name="header">User list</f:facet>

        <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:2%"/>

        <!-- data columns here, working just fine -->

        <f:facet name="footer">
            <p:commandButton value="Delete selected users" icon="ui-icon-trash" action="#{userListBean.deleteSelectedUsers()}">
                <p:confirm header="Deletion confirmation" message="Are you sure you want to delete #{fn:length(userListBean.selectedUsers)} users?" icon="ui-icon-alert" />                         
            </p:commandButton>
            Registered users: #{fn:length(userListBean.userList)}
        </f:facet>
    </p:dataTable>

    <p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="fade">
        <p:commandButton value="Yes" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check" />
        <p:commandButton value="No" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close"/>
    </p:confirmDialog>
</h:form>
```

**Backing Bean**
(userMgr handles persistence on the server, it should have nothing to do with my issue)

```
@ManagedBean(name="userListBean")
@ViewScoped
public class UserListBean {
    @EJB
    private UserManager userMgr;
    private List<UserDTO> userList;
    private UserDTO[] selectedUsers;

    public UserListBean() {

    }

    public void deleteSelectedUsers() {
        for(UserDTO u : selectedUsers)
            userMgr.deleteUser(u.getUsername());

        setUserList(userMgr.retrieveAllUsersDTO());
    }

    public List<UserDTO> getUserList() {
        if(userList == null)
            setUserList(userMgr.retrieveAllUsersDTO());

        return userList;
    }

    public void setUserList(List<UserDTO> userList) {
        this.userList = userList;
    }

    public List<UserDTO> retrieveUserList() {
        return userMgr.retrieveAllUsersDTO();
    }

    public UserDTO[] getSelectedUsers() {
        return selectedUsers;
    }

    public void setSelectedUsers(UserDTO[] selectedUsers) {
        this.selectedUsers = selectedUsers;
    }

}
```

(As a side question: the `#{fn:length(userListBean.selectedUsers)}` EL expression always returns 0. I used to think it was because of the broken selection mechanism, but could it be because the array is still empty when the confirmation dialog is rendered?)

Comment: Not an answer : `org.primefaces.model.LazyDataModel<T>` should be preferable, in this case. A view scoped bean must implement the `java.io.Serializable` interface.

Comment: First of all move all that logic in `getUserList` into a method annotated with `@PostConstruct`. Then your `getUserList` should do only what it says: gets `userList`

Comment: Thank you all, guys, I didn't know about the @PostConstruct annotation! Still lots to learn. Everything works after correcting the getter like kolossus suggested, even if I don't get what it has to do with my issue...

Answer (score 1):

You need to activate event rowSelect by adding `<p:ajax event="rowSelect"/>` to dataTable.

Comment: Mark. As. Correct.